# Do AsReadOnly returns a copy of the collection?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

In would like to know if this method returns a copy of the collection or just an instance of ReadOnlyCollection which will wrap the original collection in some way, without readding all references.

I must understand if it's going to waste memory space, will it copy all pointers to my instances?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: what wastes space is not the copy of the pointers but the copy of the object pointed/referenced... ;-)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx 'A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper that prevents..'

Comment: Sometimes, you just have to read the doc :-)

Comment: You are right, I didn't check because normally they don't specify implementation things... damn!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as you can find here: [List(Of T).AsReadOnly Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx)

> To prevent any modifications to List(Of T), expose List(Of T) only
>   through this wrapper.
>
> A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper
>   that prevents modifying the collection; therefore, if changes are made
>   to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those
>   changes.
>
> This method is an O(1) operation.

since in the last statement they say if you change the source collection the readonly collection will reflect those changes, I believe this wrapper does not re-allocate any object but does what you also described in your question.

Comment: since... I believe...
But this does not guarantee that the code does not really duplicate the elements. It just means that the coder of the wrapper (if was smart enough) had a change to do this without duplicates. 
The wrapper can, in fact, easily return a constantly updated copy of the collection (which means more waste than that of a simple copy...)

So here we have an assumption, not an answer.

Comment: This also means that if you make a change to an object in the ReadOnlyCollection you will be modifying the object in the original collection as well, so the collection is not readonly in the sense that you couldn't modify the items.

Answer (score 4):

The `AsReadOnly` method on `List<T>` just returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wrapper over the existing `List<T>`.  It doesn't copy the underlying `List<T>`

Comment: So, to clarify, you can still modify an individual item retrieved via the `IReadOnlyCollection` wrapper and have that reflected in the original collection that the read-only wrapper wraps. What you can't do is change the collection itself, like add or remove items to or from it. So this wrapper might be just one part of the immutable story, if what you want is a completely immutable collection with immutable objects. The other part is to actually have objects that cannot be mutated inside the collection (like C#9 records or other properly encapsulated objects).